# Java based Content Repository

Tags: modeshape, nosql

we are going to implement software solution which requires storing large amount of documents which need to be later searched or copied. As our application server is going to be a JBoss product (actually WildFly) we found the Modeshape project which seems pretty interesting. 
However as far as I understand from docs/presentation, this product is labeled to be strongly "**In memory**" elastic database. Since our requirement is to actually store content documents on a storage (we cannot afford losing data if our servers crash) I wonder if this choice is fit for our purpose. Or rather we should use another NoSQL based product ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModeShape does work really well and is really fast when configured as an in-memory repository that distributes the content across a cluster of machines. However, that's really only useful for really scenarios with large clusters and large volumes of data.

Most applications that use ModeShape do prefer to persist content on disk rather than rely upon a distributed in-memory grid, and ModeShape definitely supports this. Doing this involves setting up the underlying Infinispan with a cache store to persist the content where you want: on the file system, in several kinds of databases, etc. You can also independently control where ModeShape stores binary content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well that makes sense- just one question: what is the typical scenario for in-memory repository?I admit I find difficult to figure out some use cases where content data is not persisted on a storage. Thanks!

Comment: Basically you need enough machines in the cluster so that you can have enough duplicates, so that if you lose several machines you still maintain all data. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Clustering for details on all the different variations.